# how to print an image using wifi/Bluetooth connection in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, wifi

Actually I have a problem that I have to print an image or text using android app using Wifi/Bluetooth connection.

But i am not found any resource for such type of printing.

I see the app printshare. i have to do such like that.

If some one have any solution then please help me

Answer (score 0):

Some Bluetooth printers like Woosim has its own library and sample for Android. Refer to [this link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3635770/%28Android2.2_bt%29_Eng%20%5B12.03.07%5D.zip). I have used it for my project and was useful.

Comment: have you implemented this app. i want to print reciepts please share your idea

Comment: @Mahesh I have used Bixolon and it is better than Woosim. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12671847/779408