# Printer Bixolon is not connected to Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, connection, bixolon-printer

I am using pocket printer [Bixolon SPP-R200](http://www.bixolon.com/_eng/download_center/downloadsub.asp?uid=104&p_uid=38) for printing by Bluetooth in Android. I have tested my application on HTC (with Android 2.3.7) and Asus (with Android 4.0.3) and they work fine with printer.

But I have problem with Samsung Galaxy tabs P3100 and P5100 (with Android 4.0.3) in connection. The problem is when I use method `connect()` it returns 401 error means: `BXL_ERR_OPEN -> Port connection failure` and Android pairing window is opened. I enter the pin again but the problem is still remained and the printer is not connected.

I am using [the jar file in this SDK](http://www.4shared.com/zip/mv6jKQrm/bixolonSDK.html).

Does anybody know any solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was about SDK version. I had [SDK version 1.3.1](http://www.4shared.com/zip/lsLnneKK/BIXOLON_Android_SDK_V131.html) and I asked from Bixolon technical support (**techsupp@bixolon.de**) and they send me newest [version 1.4.9](http://www.4shared.com/zip/SDy72B_E/BIXOLON_Android_SDK_V149.html) and the problem solved.

**Update:**

New version [1.6.1](http://www.4shared.com/zip/Z6MCJ6Dzba/BIXOLON_Android_SDK_V161.html)

Comment: I have same problem, but with Bixolon SPP-R300. The version 1.4.9 didn't fix it.

Comment: @PedroLopes This SDK is for SPP-R200. Get SPP-R300 SDK from mentioned email

Comment: I send an email for techsupp@bixolon.de and thay send the same sdk version (1.4.9). After restar the galaxy tab and printer.. they start working... (no comments :))

Comment: Hiiiii @breceivemail, i want to use the Bixolon printer in my application and I dont have the idea how to implement this in my application , Can you please tell the where can i get the sample code to implement this ?

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal You can find it in the SDK files which is references in the answer.

Comment: yeah I tried the above link and what i found is .exe file rather than SDK .

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal You have clicked an incorrect download button in 4shared website ;)